# Extract min implemetation for heap in c++

Tags: c++, stl, heap, implementation, extract

I need to implement extract min for heap(in c++ if possible), could not get this method from STL heap.

Comment: you mean,heap_pop would return the largest and you want the smallest?

Comment: Yes and I forgot to quote, the element in the heap are not integer, its a struct with value, position and some other pointers. I am thinking STL heap cannot be used directly, Can I?

Comment: If your struct implements operator<() it will work with heap.

Answer (score 3):

Pass in `std::greater<*>` to the `std::*_heap` functions.